# How to crawl this type of urls

Tags: php, web-crawler

I'm using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser. 
How can I make it to crawl through URLs like this.
http://www.example.com/categories/index.php?id=`number from 1-1000`&article

Crawling through URL should look like this:

```
http://www.example.com/categories/index.php?id=1&article First URL
http://www.example.com/categories/index.php?id=2&article Second URL
http://www.example.com/categories/index.php?id=3&article Third URL
etc..
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` statement?

Make a page that crawl with id=`$id`, with `$id` in query string, and auto reload the page after download, incrementing `$id` each time until 1000?

Answer (score 0):

you can export post method. if you dont use all of that like with number from 1-500 must be export that with explode and list

```
<?php
list($a,$b,$c)=explode(' ','number from 1-5');
list($start,$end)=explode('-',$c);
for( $i=$start ; $i<=$end; $i++)
    echo "http://www.example.com/categories/index.php?id={$i}&article".'<br/>';
?>
```